Is it possible to customize P4V / P4Merge dark mode theme colors?
My searches haven't turned up anything so far.  I'm hoping someone here knows if it is possible and how one might do it.  I'm using p4v/p4merge version 2022.3.
As with most people, I was happy when they finally implemented a dark mode.  Unfortunately, their color choices still left something to be desired.  For instance, the below two line addition is barely visible.  The change outline was black for light mode, and for some reason is still black in dark mode, making it impossible to see on a black background except for inside the center margin.


I'd report this to support. They may be able to help you, but also, they may request a fix if it's not capable of changing this. It looks pretty visible to me, but I'm just one individual.
